# python heapq merge sort not able to write to output file

Tags: python, output, mergesort

I am trying to use Heapq Merge to merge a bunch of temp files filled with sorted integers and write to an output file. The generator in the function is returning the values. The heapq.merge() looks fine. The program builds but nothing is being written into the TestWriteOutput.txt file. I tried test writing into the output file(outf) after the line the file is opened, but nothing gets written it. TestWriteOutput.txt gets created but is blank.

```
import os
import sys
import array
import tempfile
import heapq

cwd = os.getcwd()
print "Current Directory: %s" % cwd


#generator function to return one integer at a time from the tempfile    
to a list

def numInFile(f): 
    while True:
        #set input buffer to read 8KB
        input_buffer = [int(x) for x in f.read(1024*2).split(',') if 
        x.strip().isdigit()]
        #convert list of string values into integers
        int_buffer = map(int, input_buffer)
        f.seek(0) #reset flag
        if not input_buffer:
            break
        for number in int_buffer: 
            yield number #returns one number at a time and appends to 
                           iterator



with open('age.txt', 'r+') as inf:
    with open('TestWriteOutput.txt', 'w+') as outf:
        outf.write('some test data')
        outf.write('some more data')
        #iterator for heapq merge 
        sorted_list =[]
        while True:
            a = [int(x) for x in inf.read(20000).split(',') if 
                x.strip().isdigit()]
            int_a = map(int, a)
            if not a:
                break
            f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
            #sort and write to temp file
            outf_array = sorted(int_a)
            #####print outf_array
            f.write(str(outf_array))
            f.seek(0)
            sorted_list.append(numInFile(f))



        write_to_file = array.array('i')

        #heapq merge function merges multiple ordered lists into a 
          single list
        for x in heapq.merge(*sorted_list): 
            out_buffer = 1024*4
            write_to_file.append(x)
            if len(write_to_file) >= out_buffer: 
                write_to_file.tofile(outf)
                del write_to_file[:]
        if write_to_file:
            write_to_file.tofile(outf)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the `numInFile` function you are resetting the file pointer back to the beginning of the file in each iteration.  This makes `numInFile` an inexhaustible generator.

If I change `numInFile` to:

```
def numInFile(f): 
    while True:
        #set input buffer to read 8KB
        input_buffer = [int(x) for x in f.read(1024*2).split(',') if 
        x.strip().isdigit()]
        #convert list of string values into integers
        int_buffer = map(int, input_buffer)
        if not input_buffer:
            break
        for number in int_buffer: 
            yield number #returns one number at a time and appends to iterator
```

and remove the test writes to the output file, the program completes successfully.

```
>>> import array
>>> with open('TestWriteOutput.txt') as f:
...     arr = array.array('i')
...     arr.fromfile(f, 64)
... 
>>> arr
array('i', [3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 30, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 44, 44, 46, 50, 50, 50, 52, 53, 53, 55, 56, 57, 59, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 65, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 73, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 77, 78, 79])
```

Comment: what do you mean by removing the test writes to the output file? Are you referring to the "outf.write('some test data')"?